# El Capitan: Apple Mail: How to edit an incorrect 'sent' address in the DRAFT or SENT version of an email

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I would like to know how I can edit an incorrect 'sent' address in the Draft or Sent versions of emails within Apple Mail?

It frequently happens that I have incorrectly entered an address and an hour's work bounces back.

I have tried re-entering the address to edit it, or to delete and re-enter it, but clicking on the address/name leads to nothing. Also, the effort to delete the address leads to the entire email winding up in the Trash folder.

In Gmail I can edit the address, or delete and re-enter it, but how can I do the same in Apple Mail?

Comment: Can you add the specific steps you are taking here and where the result of them starts to differ from your expectations?

Comment: From the draft folder open the mail, change email address does not work ?